# Set the aggregation text of fragments from controller

Tags: sapui5

I have a xml-fragment. I set `items` as `"{path: '/idFamiglia' }"`

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <SelectDialog
    id="idSelectDialog"
    noDataText="Nessun dato"
    title="Suggerimento"
    search="handleLocalSearch"
    liveChange="handleLocalSearch"
    confirm="handleClose"
    close="handleClose"
    items="{
      path: '/idFamiglia'
    }">
    <StandardListItem
      title="{title}"
      description="{description}"
      icon="" 
      iconDensityAware="false"
      iconInset="false"
      type="Active" />
  </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

From the controller I want set this string. I try in this methods:

```
handleValueLocalHelp : function(oEvent) {
        this.inputId = oEvent.oSource.sId;
        if (!this._oDialog) {
            this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("ui5bp.view.fragment.HintLocalDialog",this);
        }
        //1
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("idSelectDialog").setAggregation("items", "{path: '/idFamiglia'}");
        //2
        this._oDialog.bindElement("/idFamiglia");
        //3
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("idSelectDialog").bindElement("/idFamiglia");

        this._oDialog.setModel(this.getView().getModel("hint"));
        // toggle compact style
        jQuery.sap.syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), this._oDialog);
        this._oDialog.open();
    },
```

I have some errors..

1. `Uncaught Error: Aggregation 'items' of Element sap.m.List#idSelectDialog-list used with wrong cardinality (declared as 0..n)` if I try the forst mode
2. If I try the second mode it not change the string
3. the same behavior

How can I modify the aggregation string (`items` for example) from controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a solution to set a default fragment by XML-view and personalize it from controller:

```
handleValueLocalHelp : function(oEvent) {
        this.inputId = oEvent.oSource.sId;
        if (!this._oDialog) {
            this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("ui5bp.view.fragment.HintLocalDialog",this);
            this._oDialog._dialog.mAggregations.content[1].mBindingInfos.items.path="/idFamiglia";      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the control you are using (SelectDialog), the "item" aggregation can only be used with `sap.m.ListItemBase[]` whereas I can see you are binding with '**/idFamiglia**'. This is not a property binding, it is can aggregation binding.

```
var oSelectDialog = new sap.m.SelectDialog({
                multiSelect : true,
                title : "Title",
                items: {
                    path: "/",
                    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                        title: "{text}",
                        description: "{key}"
                        //selected: "{JSON>selected}" 
                    })
                },
                rememberSelections : true,
            });
```

Comment: I try to do this http://jsbin.com/catisukoge/1/edit?js
but I have this result: one item! http://imgur.com/KytxVX4